# simplify multiple filters in flutter

Tags: flutter

here is my code

```
value = data.where((i) => (i.type == 1 || i.type == 3)).toList();
      if (data.length == 0) {
        _final = null;
      } else {
        dataDefault = value .where((i) => i.isdefault == 1).toList();
      }
      if (dataDefault.length == 0) {
        data[0].isdefault = 1;
      }

      finalvalue = dataDefault.where((i) => i.isdefault == 1).toList();
```

Here is my json

```
[
  {
    "id": 129,
    "type": 3,
    "is_default": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 130,
    "type": 1,
    "is_default": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 131,
    "type": 5,
    "is_default": 1
  }
]
```

What i need is ,i need to check if the array is in type 1 or 3 if no array available i need to set first array and change as default and then i want to filter the whole array and check default field

It is working fine but i need to simplify the code and also needs to know the approach is correct

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I get the original request is:

```
if(array not contains type1 or type3){
  set array[0] to default
}
result <- get all 'is default' from array
```

Simplified version:

```
var result; // null as default

if (data != null) {
  if(data.where((i) => (i.type == 1 || i.type == 3)).isEmpty) {
    data[0].isdefault = 1;
  }
  result = data.where((i) => i.isdefault == 1).toList();
}
```

Or use null safety check `?` and `??`

```
if(data?.where((i) => (i.type == 1 || i.type == 3))?.isEmpty ?? false){
  data[0].isdefault = 1;
}

final result = data?.where((i) => i.isdefault == 1)?.toList();
```